# Laravel ManyToMany relationships and attach without pivot table from input field array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have Users and Operators, and each User can have only one operator, but Operator can have many users

So in Operator model i have:

```
public function profile() {
  return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

And in User model i have:

```
public function operator() {
  return $this->hasOne(Operator::class);
}
```

So i think i got relationships right ?

Now if i have input field to manage operators and on that i have multiselect box so i can select many users to add to that operator, input field would be something like:

```
<select name="profiles[]" id="profiles" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect2 form-control">
  @foreach($profiles as $key => $profile)
  <option value="{{ $profile->id }}">{{ $profile->name }} {{ $profile->lastname }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

On form submit that would post an array of all selected $profiles (those are users from user table)

What goes a bit tricky for me is when i am creating new operator and select which users to attach to operator, i don't know how could i add them and sync without having pivot table, and i don't need pivot table at all for this.

i have `operators` table and that one should hold operator id's and managed users id's

```
+----+-------------+---------+
| id | operator_id | user_id |
+----+-------------+---------+
|  1 |           3 |      23 |
|  2 |           3 |      28 |
|  2 |           3 |      36 |
+----+-------------+---------+
```

So how can i add (attach or connect) user id's of operators and managed users in operators table?

Here's my current controller code

```
  $user = new User;

  $user->name = $request->name;
  $user->email = $request->email;
  $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);

  $user->save();

  $user->operator()->attach(['operator_id' => $user->id,  'profile_id' => $request->profiles]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use eloquent to do a join.

```
DB::select("SELECT * FROM Users u
INNER JOIN operators o dp ON u.id = o.user_id;");
```

Just make sure you do the joins for every table you need connected